# Prestashop custom field in Product Feature not saving on Edit

Tags: php, smarty, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have created a custom field for Product Feature in my module override. Custom field for Feature is not saving in the database on edit. But on Add new feature it works fine. Here is the code for my `AdminFeaturesController.php` file:

```
<?php
class AdminFeaturesController extends AdminFeaturesControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = 'feature';
        $this->className = 'Feature';
        $this->list_id = 'feature';
        $this->identifier = 'id_feature';
        $this->lang = true;

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_feature' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Name'),
                'width' => 'auto',
                'filter_key' => 'b!name'
            ),
            'value' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Values'),
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
            'parent_id_feature' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ParentID'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
            'position' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Position'),
                'filter_key' => 'a!position',
                'align' => 'center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                'position' => 'position'
            )
        );

        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
                'icon' => 'icon-trash',
                'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')
            )
        );
        AdminController::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * AdminController::renderForm() override
     * @see AdminController::renderForm()
     */
    public function renderForm()
    {
        $this->toolbar_title = $this->l('Add a new feature');
        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Feature with Parent'),
                'icon' => 'icon-info-sign'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Name'),
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'size' => 33,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
                    'required' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Parent Feature'),
                    'name' => 'parent_id_feature',
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => Feature::getFeaturesExcept($this->context->language->id, Tools::getValue('id_feature')),
                        'id' => 'id_feature',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    ),
                    'required' => true
                )
            )
        );

        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
        {
            $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                'type' => 'shop',
                'label' => $this->l('Shop association'),
                'name' => 'checkBoxShopAsso',
            );
        }

        $this->fields_form['submit'] = array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        );

        return AdminController::renderForm();
    }

    public function renderView()
    {
        if (($id = Tools::getValue('id_feature')))
        {
            $this->setTypeValue();
            $this->list_id = 'feature_value';
            $this->position_identifier = 'id_feature_value';
            $this->position_group_identifier = 'id_feature';
            $this->lang = true;

            // Action for list
            $this->addRowAction('edit');
            $this->addRowAction('delete');

            if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($obj = new Feature((int)$id)))
            {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while updating the status for an object.').'
                    <b>'.$this->table.'</b> '.Tools::displayError('(cannot load object)');
                return;
            }

            $this->feature_name = $obj->name;
            $this->toolbar_title = $this->feature_name[$this->context->employee->id_lang];
            $this->fields_list = array(
                'id_feature_value' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('ID'),
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
                ),
                'value' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Value')
                ),
                'parent_id_feature_value' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('ParentID'),
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
                ),
                'position' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Position'),
                    'filter_key' => 'a!position',
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                    'position' => 'position'
                )
            );

            $this->_where = sprintf('AND `id_feature` = %d', (int)$id);
            $this->_orderBy = 'position';
            self::$currentIndex = self::$currentIndex.'&id_feature='.(int)$id.'&viewfeature';
            $this->processFilter();
            return AdminController::renderList();
        }
    }

    /**
     * AdminController::renderForm() override
     * @see AdminController::renderForm()
     */
    public function initFormFeatureValue()
    {
        $this->setTypeValue();

        $parent_id = Feature::getParentFeatureID((int)Tools::getValue('id_feature'));

        $this->fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Feature value'),
                'icon' => 'icon-info-sign'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Feature'),
                    'name' => 'id_feature',
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => Feature::getFeatures($this->context->language->id),
                        'id' => 'id_feature',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    ),
                    'required' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Value'),
                    'name' => 'value',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'size' => 33,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
                    'required' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Parent Feature Value'),
                    'name' => 'parent_id_feature_value',
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => FeatureValue::getFeatureValuesWithLang($this->context->language->id, $parent_id),
                        'id' => 'id_feature_value',
                        'name' => 'value'
                    ),
                    'required' => true
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
            'buttons' => array(
                'save-and-stay' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save then add another value'),
                    'name' => 'submitAdd'.$this->table.'AndStay',
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right',
                    'icon' => 'process-icon-save'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->fields_value['id_feature'] = (int)Tools::getValue('id_feature');

        // Create Object FeatureValue
        $feature_value = new FeatureValue(Tools::getValue('id_feature_value'));

        $this->tpl_vars = array(
            'feature_value' => $feature_value,
        );

        $this->getlanguages();
        $helper = new HelperForm();
        $helper->show_cancel_button = true;

        $back = Tools::safeOutput(Tools::getValue('back', ''));
        if (empty($back))
            $back = self::$currentIndex.'&token='.$this->token;
        if (!Validate::isCleanHtml($back))
            die(Tools::displayError());

        $helper->back_url = $back;
        $helper->currentIndex = self::$currentIndex;
        $helper->token = $this->token;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->override_folder = 'feature_value/';
        $helper->id = $feature_value->id;
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = false;
        $helper->tpl_vars = $this->tpl_vars;
        $helper->languages = $this->_languages;
        $helper->default_form_language = $this->default_form_language;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $this->allow_employee_form_lang;
        $helper->fields_value = $this->getFieldsValue($feature_value);
        $helper->toolbar_btn = $this->toolbar_btn;
        $helper->title = $this->l('Add a new feature value');
        $this->content .= $helper->generateForm($this->fields_form);
    }

    public function ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()
    {
        if ($this->tabAccess['edit'] === '1')
        {
            $way = (int)Tools::getValue('way');
            $id = (int)Tools::getValue('id');
            $table = 'feature';
            $positions = Tools::getValue($table);
            if (empty($positions))
            {
                $table = 'feature_value';
                $positions = Tools::getValue($table);
            }

            $new_positions = array();
            foreach ($positions as $v)
                if (!empty($v))
                    $new_positions[] = $v;

            foreach ($new_positions as $position => $value)
            {
                $pos = explode('_', $value);

                if (isset($pos[2]) && (int)$pos[2] === $id)
                {
                    if ($table == 'feature')
                    {
                        if ($feature = new Feature((int)$pos[2]))
                            if (isset($position) && $feature->updatePosition($way, $position, $id))
                                echo 'ok position '.(int)$position.' for feature '.(int)$pos[1].'\r\n';
                            else
                                echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "Can not update feature '.(int)$id.' to position '.(int)$position.' "}';
                        else
                            echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "This feature ('.(int)$id.') can t be loaded"}';

                        break;
                    }
                    elseif ($table == 'feature_value')
                    {
                        if ($feature_value = new FeatureValue((int)$pos[2]))
                            if (isset($position) && $feature_value->updatePosition($way, $position, $id))
                                echo 'ok position '.(int)$position.' for feature value '.(int)$pos[2].'\r\n';
                            else
                                echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "Can not update feature value '.(int)$id.' to position '.(int)$position.' "}';
                        else
                            echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "This feature value ('.(int)$id.') can t be loaded"}';

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my `Feature.php` is:

```
<?php
class Feature extends FeatureCore
{
    /** @var string Name */
    public $parent_id_feature;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'feature',
        'primary' => 'id_feature',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'position' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt'),
            // Parent Feature ID
            'parent_id_feature' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => false),

            // Lang fields
            'name' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        )
    );

    /**
     * Get a parent feature id for a given id_feature
     *
     * @param integer $id_feature Feature id
     * @return integer ID of parent feature
     * @static
     */
    public static function getParentFeatureID($id_feature)
    {
        return Db::getInstance()->getValue('
            SELECT parent_id_feature
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'feature` f
            WHERE f.`id_feature` = '.(int)$id_feature
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get all features for a given language except for given id
     *
     * @param integer $id_lang Language id
     * @param integer $id_feature Feature id to exclude
     * @return array Multiple arrays with feature's data
     * @static
     */
    public static function getFeaturesExcept($id_lang, $id_feature, $with_shop = true)
    {
        return Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT DISTINCT f.id_feature, f.*, fl.*
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'feature` f
        '.($with_shop ? Shop::addSqlAssociation('feature', 'f') : '').'
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'feature_lang` fl ON (f.`id_feature` = fl.`id_feature` AND fl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
        WHERE f.id_feature != '.(int)$id_feature.'
        ORDER BY f.`position` ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also hosted my plugin at GitHub https://github.com/mjawaids/advancedfeaturesvalues

Comment: have you achieved any progress?!

Comment: Nope @MuhammadNaderi