# PS 1.7 HTML in Product Feature

Tags: prestashop-1.7

**Prestashop 1.7.4.1**
I want to add two new fields only for features but that seems more complex, I already try this [Prestashop custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492642/prestashop-custom-field-in-product-feature-not-saving-on-edit) but it doesn't work for my version even following PS documentation for overwriting.
My main goal is to have a title, icon and description that allows HTML inside product features.

But that seems way too much for a simple task, so instead I'd like to know how I can enable the WYSIWYG textarea, I have manages to change the input from type text to textarea:

```
array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->trans('Value', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'name' => 'value',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'size' => 255,
                    'hint' => $this->trans('Invalid characters:', array(), 'Admin.Notifications.Info').' <>;=#{}',
                    'required' => true
                ),
```

So, the question is, how to enable HTML editor in product features.
I'm new in PrestaShop, I have read in forums but no help I can find regarding this implementation.

Thank you in advance.
**UPDATE 10-10-2018 6:56 (GTM-5)**

I Fix the HTML part, now is the matter of validation, it still blocking all html tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your field array: `'autoload_rte' => true` that way you can activate the TinyMce editor for Features input value, If I'm not mistaken that is on function: `initFormFeatureValue()`, on that same function look for `Tools::safeOutput(Tools::getValue('back', ''));` and add true before `);` check if that works.
**UPDATE**
Open `FeaturesValue.php` in folder `classes`, look in line `53`

```
'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),`
```

Replace it with:

```
'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
```

Then in your TPL `product-details.tpl` look for:

```
  {block name='product_features'}
    {if $product.grouped_features}
      <section class="product-features">
        <p class="h6">{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
        <dl class="data-sheet">
          {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
            <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
            <dd class="value">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</dd>
          {/foreach}
        </dl>
      </section>
    {/if}
  {/block}
```

Replace it with:

```
{block name='product_features'}
  {if $product.grouped_features}
     <section class="product-features">
        <p class="h6">{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
        <dl class="data-sheet">
          {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
             <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
             <dd class="value">{$feature.value nofilter}</dd>
          {/foreach}
        </dl>
     </section>
  {/if}
{/block}
```

In this block you only need to change `{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}` for `{$feature.value nofilter}` and that is it...
I hope it works, keep in mind that while in product edit/new when adding a new feature you can only select from what you have, what I mean is that if you want a custom value while editing a product the input for feature custom value will still in `type text`, but I hope that with this you have a better idea on how to change the rest.

Comment: thats what I did to show the tinymcs but saving the html is another story, can't find where to change from STRING to TEXT_HTML... thanks.

Comment: to be new in `SOF` you just started on the right path!, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop use HTML escape on tpl files:

```
<td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
<td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
```

you have to change it to display HTML (on your theme):

```
<td>{$feature.name}</td>
<td>{$feature.value}</td>
```

Comment: Yes I got that, the problem right now is when saving features is not accepting the HTML to be saved, it seems to be with the validation in Tool.php or AdminFeaturesControlller.php but I can't find it...